# Android: ImageView disable scaling

Tags: android, imageview, scale

How can I disable automatic scaling in imageView?

Comment: tryed to wrap_content instead of fill_parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try different `android:scaleType` parameter

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:scaleType="center" />
```

Answer (score 8):

place your images in a folder called drawable-nodpi. This prevents automatic scaling of images.

Answer (score 0):

Android automatically scale your image to some dimensions.
So, put image into correct folder, like drawable-hdpi or drawable-xhdpi or other.